# php, how not to let a user enter a past date?

Tags: php

i have a form and a input where i can place a date in this format `m/d/y`
`<input type="text" name="date_ts" size=8 maxlength=8  value="">`

i need to figure out a way of not letting the user input a date that is in the past.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the date to an Unix timestamp ([`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and compare it with [`time();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) (note: will not work with today)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtotime($_POST['date_ts']) < time()) // Past date was posted
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use JS to check if the date entered is less than today's date. Problem nailed at first step. If not goto step 2
2. `strtomtime()` is wonderful, use this `date("m-d-Y", strtotime('now'))` to get in `dd-mm-yyyy` format or any other suitable for your comparison, look at http://php.net/date for more `date()` formatting options

Comment: 1) dd-mm-yyyy strings are *not* suitable for comparison. 2) `strtotime('now')`? Ouch. Just use `time()`.

Comment: thats why I said any other suitable for comparison, `strtotime('now')` will give you now, its more than today :)